# Get link by id API/URL

Tags: php, api, curl, file-get-contents

I have this code

```
    <?php
// The result of the request:
$content = <<<END_OF_STRING
[{"id":"2972","name":"MBC 1","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TR/mbc1-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC1En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc1.png"},{"id":"1858","name":"MBC 2","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc2-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC2En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc2.png"},{"id":"1859","name":"MBC 3","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc3-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc3.png"}]
END_OF_STRING;

$items = json_decode($content);

// To access the first one:
echo "\nFirst link = " . $items[0]->link . "\n";
```

I want to get link by id.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More ore less what you need could be:

```php
<?php
// The result of the request:
$content = <<<END_OF_STRING
[{"id":"2972","name":"MBC 1","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TR/mbc1-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC1En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc1.png"},{"id":"1858","name":"MBC 2","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc2-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC2En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc2.png"},{"id":"1859","name":"MBC 3","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc3-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc3.png"}]
END_OF_STRING;

$items = json_decode($content);
$id = 1859;
$desiredLink = '';

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($id == $item->id) {
        $desiredLink = $item->link;
    }
}

// To access the first one:
echo "\nDesired link = " . $desiredLink . "\n";
```

This will output: `Desired link = http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc3-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1`

If you prefer, ... I've also implemented a little class to do the same job:

```
class Finder {
    public function __construct(private string $content) {}
    public function getLinkById(int $id) {
        $items = json_decode($this->content);
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($id == $item->id) {
                return $item->link;
            }
        }
    }
}

// To access the first one:
echo "\nDesired link = " . (new Finder($content))->getLinkById($id) . "\n";
```